# Explanation for images with width and height to be responsive

Tags: html, css, image

Can anyone explain to me the concept of images to be responsiveness? And where we should use width and height for images some told me that .it is not correct to take width and height for images can anyone elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

For image Make width:100% and height: auto; that will work for responsive. 
but the parent element may or may not have width. Fixed width and fixed height is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you use responsive images in your page it means you show different sizes of an image based on screen size. for example, on mobile screen you show a smaller image and on desktop screen you display the same image but with bigger resolution. this logic can be done through html or css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fully responsive image - you can use div with background image, background-size: cover(or 100%) and background-position: center center